# Is it OK to say "Thanks all the same" in this scenario?

Tags: phrase-request, politeness, conversation

Someone sent a message to me unexpectedly and I replied with a question mark, then he told me that he just made a mistake by selecting the wrong recipient. I read the message and found that it is very helpful(also to me).

I thought I should say thank you, but it seemed awkward because I had not asked him for the favor, then I finished the conversation with a "Thanks all the same".

I know "thanks all the same" implies that I had asked for help(but the response was unhelpful), but the reality is that I had not(but helpful). I wonder how to thank him in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't say ***thanks all the same***, for the reason you stated yourself: *it implies that you had asked for help*.

Instead I would shortly explain what I am grateful for:

> grateful for this [serendipity](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/serendipity)/happy accident!

Comment: I'm not convinced that 'thanks all the same' would not be an appropriate response to unrequested help. You can use 'all the same' to mean 'in spite of' or 'nevertheless'. I did not ask for this help, which was intended for someone else. I found it useful nevertheless.

Comment: Overseas scam call centre: Hi Mr Harvey, we'd like to help you with a claim for your recent car accident. Me: I don't have a car, but thanks all the same! Overseas scam call centre: <click>

Comment: Agreed. I wouldn't use "thanks all the same" because of the sarcastic tone or the blase` attitude that almost always accompanies it.

Comment: blase` or blasé?

Comment: @FeliniusRex - I don't agree that 'all the same' necessarily implies sarcastic intent.